# Django: Persist the filter with paginator

Tags: python, django

I have  list pages showing event that can be filtered by city, I'm also using Django paginator. My issue is how do I persist the filter when on another page?

example view.py not actual code..

```
event_list = Event.objects.filter(city=something)
paginator = Paginator(event_list, 1) # Show 25 contacts per page
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually pass the extra get variables which will be later used for filtering:

```
<a href="?page={{ paginator.next_page_number }}&my_filter_a={{ my_filter_a }}&my_filter_b={{ my_filter_b }}">Next</a>
```