# Django: How to get current selected element in form

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I'm trying to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886293/django-django-tables2-pagination-and-filtering). There, I'm trying to use django-tables2 pagination with filters. The problem is the filter does not persist with pagination. However, since the pagination links use GET method, I'm trying to cram the "current" value of `my_filter` in the querystring.

My harebrained idea: when the `index` view is called, I can unpack the current value of my_filter and re-apply the filter to my table.

I've created a drop down field containing some choices:

```
MY_CHOICES = (
    ('Apple', 'Apple'),
    ('Ball', 'Ball'),
    ('Cat', 'Cat'),
    )
```

My model:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    my_choices = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=MY_CHOICES, default="", verbose_name="Choices")
```

My form:

```
class TestFilter(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestOrder
        fields = ('my_choices',)
```

My view:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        my_filter = TestFilter(request.POST)
        my_selection = my_filter.cleaned_data['my_choices']
        my_filter = TestFilter(request.POST)
    else:
        my_filter = TestFilter()  

    return render(request, 'my_app/index.html', {'my_filter': my_filter})
```

Is there is a way to get the "current" value of the `my_filter` drop down? In other words, is it possible to retrieve data displayed on the web page, *after* the page has finished loading (i.e. the current selected value of `my_filter`)?

Comment: `my_filter.cleaned_data` can only be accessed _after_ `if my_field.is_valid():`

Comment: According to the documentation:
Tables pass data via the querystring to indicate ordering and pagination preferences.

Comment: Yes, this is why I need to get the 'current' value of the drop down, so I can pass it as an argument to the querystring.

Comment: Shouldn't it then be accessible through request.GET?

Comment: Yes you're right. @serafeim helped me understand when to use GET vs POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886293/django-django-tables2-pagination-and-filtering) resolved my query here.

In essence, I should use `request.GET` for filtering.